# scalar ivar & memory warning or viewUnLoad

Tags: objective-c, didreceivememorywarning

I have an UIViewController with scalar ivars. I would like to know what will happen when a controller will receive a memory warning.

testBool will be kept without changes or will be reseted ?

class.h

```
@interface myView : UIViewController
{
BOOL testBool;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you receive a memory warning, YOU need to react to it. The system will try to help you (freeing VC's views and calling loadView / viewDidLoad again when needed) but you need to take care of all your objects.

Speaking of objects.. if you define "BOOL*" this will be a pointer.. i don't think you really want this (you will need to allocate some memory and assign this memory address to testBool so you can access the real scalar value with *testBool = YES/NO and free this memory on [self dealloc]).

In general, cocoa memory management applies to OBJECTS only. If you mess around with pointers to scalars you have to deal yourself with memory (de)allocation. You should use scalar ivars or Foundation-Types like NSNumber. If you use ARC, you don't even have to care a lot about the memory management (retain/release). Only when you receive memory warnings, you should assign `nil` to the variables (ARC will handle the memory management).

Comment: Martin, I have updated the code above from BOOL pointer to BOOL scalar.

Comment: Martin, if I understand well we should non worry about scalars due to the fact that cocoa management is only about objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not going to be released, when you received a warning, just

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

Its called. This is telling you that your class is taking a lot of memory,so you should release some things that you are not using.

But if you receive some memory warnings, dealloc is going to be called and for sure your var is going to dissapear.